# in databricks does array_union maintain order

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

```html
MERGE INTO final_table a
USING 
(
select student_id,array_agg(distinct subject) new_subject
from changes_table b
group by 1,2
) b
on a.student_id =  b.student_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a.subject = array_union(array(new_subject),array(subject)),
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (student_id,subject) VALUES (b.student_id,new_subject)
```

```
changed_table values = ["sql","python"] 
Final_table values = ["sql","scala"]

Result values ["sql", "python", "scala"]
```

The output that I am getting is correct.

Question is that would it maintain the array_union maintain order in databricks ?

Comment: can you provide information about what kind of maintain order are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_union` is a Spark function and we can see its implementation: [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b6bb6fa20f40aeedea2fb87008e9cce76c54e28/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/collectionOperations.scala#L3964) on GitHub.

If you examine it, you will see how it's iterating through both arrays *in sequence* and adding unique entries to an array buffer, which becomes the final result. Therefore yes, it does preserve order.